# How to add brackets in heading of a table column in database?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to create a database containing multiple tables using postgres 11 and i'm currently creating a table which contain brackets in the heading of the column (as shown as follows).

Table - supp_details

```
supp_id|supp_name | supp_weight(Kg)|
```

Can i add units to the heading and what is the proper way to do so with sql?

I'm a fresher to query writing, so please help me with this.

Comment: `supp_weight_kg`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You *could* place the column name in quotes, e.g. use `"supp_weight(Kg)"`, but it is best to avoid placing special characters or keywords as object names.  Instead, I suggest using the following name:

```
supp_weight_kg
```

It is just a single string requiring no escaping, and makes it clear what the units are.  A better option might be to just use `supp_weight`, and maybe just keep a note somewhere that the column uses kilograms as the unit by default.

Comment: Thank you for the response. It will helpful in the future as well..

Answer (score 3):

You will need to use [quoted identifiers](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS) but I **strongly** recommend not to do that:

```
create table supp_details
(
  supp_id           integer, 
  supp_name         text, 
  "supp_weight(kg)" integer
);
```

Comment: The word **strongly** is pretty important. Nobody should do this. There is a possibility to assign comments to table fields. It's good place for these additional informations.

Comment: @PavelStehule i didn't get what you said. can you explain it

Comment: Postgres allows to define "comments" to any objects and for tables the comments can be defined for fields. see `COMMENT ON table.column IS 'some text'`

Answer (score 0):

Adding bracket symbols into your column names is possible but probably a bad idea.  If you want to micromanage the name just for display purposes of the end result, you should probably do it in an alias, using the AS keyword.

```
SELECT supp_id, supp_name, supp_weight AS "supp_weight(Kg)" FROM ...
```

Or add the decorations on the client side before it displays the results.